# Плеер javascript

Tags: javascript

Помогите пожалуйста, я не знаю как реализовать плеер(js).
Допустим, у меня есть две кнопки. Если нажать на первую кнопку, произведётся какой-то звук. Если на вторую, другой звук.
Как мне реализовать код, что бы эти кнопки использовали один и тот же плеер?

Comment: Диле́мма — полемический довод с двумя противоположными положениями, исключающими друг друга и не допускающими возможность третьего. В повседневной речи употребляется тогда, когда оба варианта нежелательны, и выбор происходит по принципу «меньшего зла». (учимся использовать слова правильно)

Comment: Меняйте кнопками **src**, а плеяк пусть будет один. Всего делов-то.

Comment: @Опан история немного сложней при кастомном UI.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<audio id=audio controls></audio>
<br /><br />
<button onclick="audio.src='http://mysynthesizer.github.io/index.hetemeel/track1.mp3'; audio.play()"> Трек-1 </button> 
<button onclick="audio.src='http://mysynthesizer.github.io/index.hetemeel/track2.mp3'; audio.play()"> Трек-2 </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const audio = new Audio();
const treck = [
  'http://mysynthesizer.github.io/index.hetemeel/track2.mp3', 'http://mysynthesizer.github.io/index.hetemeel/track1.mp3'
];

const playTrec = t => {
  audio.src = t
  audio.play()
}

document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((s, i) => {
  s.addEventListener('click', () => {
    playTrec(treck[i])
  })
})
```

```html
<button> Трек-1 </button>
<button> Трек-2 </button>
```

Comment: Кто разрешал использовать мои авторские треки? :-) Ладно, разрешаю.

Comment: Не обессудь, лень было искать...